# Search the records with the specific word as starting word

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search for a record in MySQL database, But when use command like this:

```
$sql="SELECT name FROM students WHERE name LIKE '%name%'";
```

it returns all the records with the character it contains.

But I want to search for just the records with only name starting with that character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove one of the wildcards, try it like this:

```
$sql="SELECT name FROM students WHERE name LIKE 'name%'";
```

The `%` character means any character on this side.

So if you do `%name` it means, anything that ends with `name` and if you do `name%` it means anything that starts with name. However, when you do `%name%` it means, anything that contains the word `name`

Some examples:

```
SELECT name FROM students WHERE name LIKE 'name%'
```

Would match 'namemy' but not 'myname'

```
SELECT name FROM students WHERE name like '%name'
```

Would match 'myname' but not 'namemy'

```
SELECT name FROM students WHERE name like '%name%'
```

Would match both 'myname' AND 'namemy'

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$sql="SELECT name FROM students WHERE name LIKE 'name%'";
```

**Explanation:**

`%`  Allows you to match any string of any length (including zero length)

1. `%` before string will allow you to match your required column value ends with your string, for example:

   ```
   $sql="SELECT name FROM students WHERE name LIKE '%name'";
   ```
2. `%` after string  will allow you to match required column value starts with your string, for example:

   ```
   $sql="SELECT name FROM students WHERE name LIKE 'name%'";
   ```
3. `%` before and after string will allow you to match required column value that contain string anywhere., for example:

   ```
   $sql="SELECT name FROM students WHERE name LIKE '%name%'";
   ```